# Spring boot entity not getting updated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

following are my controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateApi", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateApiPost(@ModelAttribute("api") Api api, HttpServletRequest request) {
    adminAppLogger.info("Attempting to update api with id {}:"+api.getId()+" title: {}"+api.getTitle());
    apiService.save(api);

    MultipartFile apiImage = api.getApiImage();

    if(!apiImage.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = apiImage.getBytes();
            String name = api.getId() + ".png";

            Files.delete(Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/image/api/"+name));

            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/api/" + name)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        adminAppLogger.info("Successfully updated api with title {}:"+api.getTitle()+" {"+api+"}");


        return "redirect:/api/apiInfo?id="+api.getId();
    }
```

This is my GET method when I click on update button it shows my a form with already present entity info from MYSQL DB

```
@RequestMapping("/updateApi")
public String updateApi(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {
    Api api = apiService.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("api", api);

    return "updateApi";
}
```

I am expecting it to update db but it inserts a whole new entry in db : logs are:
Hibernate: insert into api_info (active, author, category, code, date, description, data_json, number_of_lines, progress, project, response_json, title, url) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Follwing is my service and repository :

```
@Service
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService{

    @Autowired
    private ApiRepository apiRepository;

    public Api save(Api api) {
        return apiRepository.save(api);
    }

    public List<Api> findAll() {
        return (List<Api>) apiRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Api findOne(Long id) {
        return apiRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void removeOne(Long id) {
        apiRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Repository :

```
public interface ApiRepository extends CrudRepository<Api, Long>{

}
```

Comment: what does this log show? "adminAppLogger.info("Attempting to update api with id {}:"+api.getId()+" title: {}"+api.getTitle());"
Id the same as the record you want to update?

Comment: its shows: Attempting to update api with id {}:null title: {}fsfsdf

Comment: As you can see ID is null so my answer is valid.

Comment: yep, exactly. if you wanna update, then id must be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting INSERTs where you would expect UPDATEs to happens, it means that:

- Either entity passed to `save` has no ID set, thus `persist` is called under the hood
- Or entitywith given ID is not present in the database thus merge fails (and maybe it is persisted as fallback, dunno)

Check if entities has set ID field.

Since I don't see id field on insert fields list, I think it is missing ID as it would be included in insert otherwise.

Comment: Oh yes , I didn't have setId in my Api entity, man you guys are great...such a silly thing but pretty important